# Why is the field reported missing in CURSOR creation?

Tags: mysql

DECLARE CURSOR in MySQL Stored procedure gives me a "Unknown column" error

Same SQL works standalone SQL statement.

Below is the heading portion of the CURSOR declaration.

```
 DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
    count(*) as curl,
    ISM_MessageDelivered
FROM
    instantmessagesarchive
.
.
.
```

Get: Unknown column ISM_MessageDelivered in field list. The field is definitely in the instanmessagesarchive table and if I remove that field in the cursor definition above, then the cursor doesn't complain.

Would appreciate any ideas what's wrong with this syntax since the same SQL (without the CURSOR) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you declare the variables where store in the data?

For instance:

```
DECLARE curl_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ISM_MessageDelivered BOOLEAN;

    SELECT
    count(*) as curl_count,
    ISM_MessageDelivered
FROM
    instantmessagesarchive
.
.
.
```

note that you must have to name your variables as you use the query.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I added the DECLARE as you suggested to the top of the StoredProc, but now get "incorrect number of fetch variables". After trying to solve this for several hours, I am now reading the data from JDBC and doing this computation in Java (and generating a CSV from there). I appreciate your help and suggestion.